# How to make textview continue below another textview if multiple lines

Tags: android, android-layout

Iam populating a RecyclerView with items of two textviews, one is the label(Left textview) and the other holds the content (Right textview). When the contents text gets long it will create multiple lines. Now if we have more the one line I want the text to continue below the label, is this possible? If not how do I make the textviews vertical if multiple lines in content textview?

[image: Problem Description]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#667889"

    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/content"

    tools:text="Eros donec ac odio tempor" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/label"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:text="Content - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Text should continue below, something like this [link](https://imgur.com/UDzIdFF)

Comment: Please show us your layout code.

Comment: @Neptulon Have you got any luck to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The property you want to use is

```
android:ems=""
android:maxLines=""
```

ems means font size and max lines means how many lines you want in your text view.
These are the property you want to use in XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a single textView, Just use StringBuilder and append text to builder abs set that string builder to text view

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("Your Text1 );
builder.append("Your Text2 );
```

then set this to textView

```
textView.setText(builder);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

> The idea here, is to take the layout which is a constraint layout
>   containing two TextViews:

- **tv_fixed** (fixed from point of view I don't care about its text)
- **tv_variable** (variable from point of view that further processing on its text is needed)

**Note:** let's call the text we are working on as **Ourtext**

and dynamically add another TextView (**tv_variable_plus**) below tv_fixed and tv_variable. TextView tv_variable_plus will help tv_variable in displaying **Ourtext** in such a way to provide the desired effect.

**Note:** A Barrier is dynamically added with reference id's (tv_fixed and tv_variable ids) and tv_variable_plus is actually added below this Barrier.
The purpose of this barrier is to make sure that tv_variable_plus text will not mix with the other TextViews text.

**How is OurText divided between TextView tv_variable and the added TextView tv_variable_plus?**

The idea here is (when **Ourtext** changes using the provided `setText(String text1, String text)` method):

- Loop across each character of **Ourtext**, get the width `cCharWidth` (in pixels) of each character, increment `cTotalCharWidth` (which is counting the width of all characters inside OurText), then check if `cTotalCharWidth` is greater than TextView tv_variable width (-padding), and if so than we can consider that we reached a new line (lines are counted using `cLineCounter`).
- As a next step, we need to check if number of lines counted `cLineCounter` multiplied by TextView tv_variable line height `int cLineHeight = tv_variable.getLineHeight();` is greater than all TextView tv_fixed lines 
  height `int tAllLineHeight = tv_fixed.getLineCount() * tv_fixed.getLineHeight();`, and if so than we can consider that the current character index (`i`) is the **Ourtext** text index at which TextView tv_variable text ends and tv_variable_plus text starts.

> 2) TextViewInADifferentWay.class

```
public class TextViewInADifferentWay {

private final String TAG = TextViewInADifferentWay.class.getSimpleName();
private Context context;
private ConstraintLayout cl;
private TextView tv_fixed = null;
private TextView tv_variable = null;
private TextView tv_variable_plus = null;
private String text = "";
public static final int CALCULATION_MODE_SINGLE_LINE = 0;
public static final int CALCULATION_MODE_LINES_TOTAL_HEIGHT = 1;
private int calculationMode = CALCULATION_MODE_LINES_TOTAL_HEIGHT;

public TextViewInADifferentWay(@NonNull Context context,
                               @NonNull View layout) {
    this(context, layout, CALCULATION_MODE_LINES_TOTAL_HEIGHT);
}

public TextViewInADifferentWay(@NonNull Context context,
                               @NonNull View layout,
                               int calculationMode) {

    this.context = context;
    if(calculationMode == CALCULATION_MODE_SINGLE_LINE ||
            calculationMode == CALCULATION_MODE_LINES_TOTAL_HEIGHT){
        this.calculationMode = calculationMode;
    }
    setUpLayout(context, layout);
}

private void setUpLayout(Context context, View layout) {

    if (layout instanceof ConstraintLayout) {
        this.cl = (ConstraintLayout) layout;
        if (this.cl.getChildCount() == 2) {
            View child1 = this.cl.getChildAt(0);
            View child2 = this.cl.getChildAt(1);
            if (child1 instanceof TextView
                    && child2 instanceof TextView) {
                this.tv_fixed = (TextView) child1;
                this.tv_variable = (TextView) child2;
                this.text = this.tv_variable.getText().toString();
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Must have two children!!");
        }
    }
    if (tv_fixed != null && tv_variable != null) {

        /**
         * Add a barrier in the bottom of tv_fixed and tv_variable in order to always write to
         * the bottom of the view with the largest height
         */
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params_ = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        Barrier barrier = new Barrier(context);
        int bId = ViewCompat.generateViewId();
        barrier.setId(bId);
        barrier.setType(Barrier.BOTTOM);
        barrier.setReferencedIds(new int[]{tv_fixed.getId(),
                tv_variable.getId()});
        barrier.setLayoutParams(params_);

        this.cl.addView(barrier);

        ConstraintSet constraintSet_ = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet_.clone(this.cl);
        constraintSet_.connect(bId, ConstraintSet.START, this.cl.getId(), ConstraintSet.START);
        constraintSet_.connect(bId, ConstraintSet.END, this.cl.getId(), ConstraintSet.END);
        constraintSet_.applyTo(this.cl);

        /**
         * Add a TextView (tv_variable_plus)
         */
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tv_variable_plus = new TextView(context);
        int tId = ViewCompat.generateViewId();
        tv_variable_plus.setId(tId);

        //TODO: Clone as much attribute from base textView (tv_variable)
        tv_variable_plus.setTextSize(convertPixelsToDp(tv_variable.getTextSize(),
                context));
        tv_variable_plus.setTextColor(tv_variable.getCurrentTextColor());
        tv_variable_plus.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        tv_variable_plus.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
        tv_variable_plus.setLayoutParams(params);
        this.cl.addView(tv_variable_plus);

        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(this.cl);
        constraintSet.connect(tv_variable_plus.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, bId, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
        constraintSet.connect(tv_variable_plus.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, this.cl.getId(), ConstraintSet.START);
        constraintSet.connect(tv_variable_plus.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, this.cl.getId(), ConstraintSet.END);
        constraintSet.applyTo(this.cl);

        //set Text to default text (xml based) in order to re-calculate
        setText(tv_fixed.getText().toString(), text);

    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Both TextViews must be non null!!");
    }
}

/**
 * This method converts device specific pixels to density independent pixels.
 *
 * @param px      A value in px (pixels) unit. Which we need to convert into db
 * @param context Context to get resources and device specific display metrics
 * @return A float value to represent dp equivalent to px value
 */
private static float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context) {
    return px / ((float) context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
}

public void calculate() {

    //TODO: Clone as much attribute from base textView (tv_variable)
    tv_variable_plus.setTextSize(convertPixelsToDp(tv_variable.getTextSize(),
            context));
    tv_variable_plus.setTextColor(tv_variable.getCurrentTextColor());
    tv_variable_plus.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    tv_variable_plus.setIncludeFontPadding(false);

    int cTotalCharWidth = 0;
    int cLineCounter = 1;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        int cLineHeight = tv_variable.getLineHeight();
        int tLineHeight = tv_fixed.getLineHeight();
        int tAllLineHeight = tv_fixed.getLineCount() * tLineHeight;
        String c = String.valueOf(text.charAt(i));
        float cCharWidth = getStringWidth(tv_variable, c);
        //Log.i(TAG, c + "-- w: " + cCharWidth);
        cTotalCharWidth += cCharWidth;
        if (cTotalCharWidth >= (tv_variable.getWidth() -
                tv_variable.getPaddingLeft() - tv_variable.getPaddingRight())) {
            //Log.i(TAG, "New Line after " + c + " (" + i + ")");
            if (calculationMode == CALCULATION_MODE_LINES_TOTAL_HEIGHT) {
                cTotalCharWidth = 0;
                if (((2 * cLineCounter) * cLineHeight) >= (tAllLineHeight)) {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            } else if (calculationMode == CALCULATION_MODE_SINGLE_LINE) {
                if (cLineCounter == 1) {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            cLineCounter += 1;
        }
    }
    if (index != 0) {
        tv_variable.setText(text.substring(0, index));
        tv_variable_plus.setText(text.substring(index));
        tv_variable_plus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        tv_variable.setText(text);
        tv_variable_plus.setText("");
        tv_variable_plus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private float getStringWidth(TextView tv, String text) {
    Paint textPaint = tv.getPaint();
    float sWidth = textPaint.measureText(text); // in pixels
    return sWidth;
}

public TextView getTvFixed() {
    return this.tv_fixed;
}

public TextView getTvVariable() {
    return this.tv_variable;
}

public TextView getTvVariablePlus() {
    return this.tv_variable_plus;
}

public TextViewInADifferentWay setCalculationMode(int calculationMode) {
    if (calculationMode == CALCULATION_MODE_SINGLE_LINE ||
            calculationMode == CALCULATION_MODE_LINES_TOTAL_HEIGHT) {
        if (calculationMode != this.calculationMode) {
            this.calculationMode = calculationMode;
            calculate();
        }
    }
    return TextViewInADifferentWay.this;
}

public TextViewInADifferentWay setText(String text1, String text) {
    this.text = text;
    tv_fixed.setText(text1);
    tv_variable.setText(text);
    if (tv_variable_plus != null) {
        tv_variable_plus.setText("");
        /**
         * make sure that views are inflated before calculating
         */
        final ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = this.cl.getViewTreeObserver();
        viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                cl.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                calculate();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    return TextViewInADifferentWay.this;
}

public String getText() {
    return this.text;
}

}
```

> 3) Example:

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private RecyclerView rv_before;
private RecyclerView rv_after;
private Button b;
private List<String> one = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> two = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    one.add("Hello, how is work?");
    two.add("Hello, everything is fine, thank you for asking.");
    one.add("?");
    two.add("How are you today?");
    one.add("I not feeling well!");
    two.add("Are you sick, you seem extremely tired?");
    one.add("I've got flu");
    two.add("Go home and please stay there until you feel better. " +
            "You don't want to spread your infection!");

    rv_before = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_before);
    rv_before.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManagerB = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    rv_before.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManagerB);

    rv_after = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_after);
    rv_after.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManagerA = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    rv_after.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManagerA);

    CustomRecyclerViewAdapter customRecyclerViewAdapterB = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, true, one, two);
    rv_before.setAdapter(customRecyclerViewAdapterB);

    CustomRecyclerViewAdapter customRecyclerViewAdapterA = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, false, one, two);
    rv_after.setAdapter(customRecyclerViewAdapterA);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            List<String> fixed = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> variable = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < one.size(); i++) {
                int oneI = new Random().nextInt(one.size());
                fixed.add(one.get(oneI));
                variable.add(two.get(oneI));
            }
            customRecyclerViewAdapterB.changeText(fixed, variable);
            customRecyclerViewAdapterA.changeText(fixed, variable);
        }
    });
}

private class CustomRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

    private final Context context;
    private List<String> fixed;
    private List<String> variable;
    private final boolean before;

    public CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, boolean before,
                                     List<String> fixed, List<String> variable) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.before = before;
        this.fixed = fixed;
        this.variable = variable;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item, parent, false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(layout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(!before) { // after
            holder.textViewInADifferentWay.setText(fixed.get(position), variable.get(position));
        }else{ // before
            TextView tv_fixed = (TextView) holder.text_view_in_a_different_way.findViewById(R.id.tv_fixed);
            TextView tv_variable = (TextView) holder.text_view_in_a_different_way.findViewById(R.id.tv_variable);
            tv_fixed.setText(fixed.get(position));
            tv_variable.setText(variable.get(position));
        }
        holder.tv.setText("Item " + position + " top");
        holder.tv1.setText("Item " + position + " bottom");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return fixed.size();
    }

    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextViewInADifferentWay textViewInADifferentWay;
        private final View text_view_in_a_different_way;
        private final TextView tv;
        private final TextView tv1;

        public CustomViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text_view_in_a_different_way = (View)
                    itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_in_a_different_way);
            if(!before) { // after
                textViewInADifferentWay = new TextViewInADifferentWay(context,
                        text_view_in_a_different_way);
            }
            tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            tv1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        }
    }

    public void changeText(List<String> fixed, List<String> variable) {
        this.fixed = fixed;
        this.variable = variable;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/rl"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change Data Set"
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
</Button>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/b"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:weightSum="100">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="26.5"
    android:id="@+id/rv_before">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="47"
        android:text="Divider (before - after)"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">
    </TextView>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="26.5"
    android:id="@+id/rv_after">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**recycler_view_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!-- other stuff -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="Item">
</TextView>

<!-- other stuff -->

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text_view_in_a_different_way"
    layout="@layout/text_view_in_a_different_way">
</include>

<!-- other stuff -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:text="Item">
</TextView>

<!-- other stuff -->

</LinearLayout>
```

**text_view_in_a_different_way.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cl"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_fixed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_variable"
    android:text="Hello World World Hello" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_variable"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_fixed"
    android:text="Hello World Hello World Hello World" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> 4) Output

[image: output]

> 5) GitHub

[TextViewInADifferentWay](https://github.com/Brainnovo/TextViewInADifferentWay)